# Perl script runs in linux terminal, but errors in browser

Tags: linux, perl, browser

I'm trying to run this simple script in the browser and it keeps erroring out. If I run it in linux, it runs fine.

Script - test.pl:

```
#!/home/biotools/perl/5.10.0/bin/perl
use lib '/home/biotools/current/lib/site_perl/5.10.0';
use lib '/people/users/123456/classPath/lib';
use IngresLXSetupNoLog;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Path::Class;  # this is line 8

my $dir = dir('./mydir'); # foo/bar

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

# Iterate over the content of foo/bar
while (my $file = $dir->next) {

    # See if it is a directory and skip
    next if $file->is_dir();

    # Print out the file name and path
    print $file->stringify . "\n";
}
```

Error:

```
[Tue Nov 29 08:46:29 2011] [error] Can't locate Path/Class.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /people/users/123456/classPath/lib /home/biotools/current/lib/site_perl/5.10.0/x86_64-linux /home/biotools/current/lib/site_perl/5.10.0 /usr/local/biotools/perl/5.10.0/lib/5.10.0/x86_64-linux /usr/local/biotools/perl/5.10.0/lib/5.10.0 /usr/local/biotools/perl/5.10.0/lib/site_perl/5.10.0/x86_64-linux /usr/local/biotools/perl/5.10.0/lib/site_perl/5.10.0 .) at /projects/apps/dev/cgi-bin/miscellaneous/studyinfo/test.pl line 8.
[Tue Nov 29 08:46:29 2011] [error] BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /projects/apps/dev/cgi-bin/miscellaneous/studyinfo/test.pl line 8.
[Tue Nov 29 08:46:29 2011] [error] Premature end of script headers: test.pl
```

Comment: It doesn't run "in the brower".  When run from a web server it uses its username (like apache) and with its permissions, not yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is the `.pm` file that defines `Path::Class`? (If you don't know, try adding `BEGIN { print "@INC\n"; }` right before line 8, and running the script from the command line.)

You need to add its parent directory to your `@INC`, using another `use lib '...';` pragma.

Comment: If i add your code, it shows that the .pm is located at `/people/users/123456/classPath/lib /home/biotools/current/lib/site_perl/5.10.0/x86_64-linux /home/biotools/current/lib/site_perl/5.10.0 /usr/local/biotools/perl/5.10.0/lib/5.10.0/x86_64-linux /usr/local/biotools/perl/5.10.0/lib/5.10.0 /usr/local/biotools/perl/5.10.0/lib/site_perl/5.10.0/x86_64-linux /usr/local/biotools/perl/5.10.0/lib/site_perl/5.10.0 .`

Comment: I installed the Path::Class module in `use lib '/people/users/123456/classPath';` so i have Class.pm in  `/people/users/123456/classPath/lib/Path/Class.pm`

Comment: @Catfish: To clarify, that's a *list* of directories, of which *one* will contain a `Path` directory that contains `Class.pm`. Oddly, the only difference between the `@INC` from the command-line and the `@INC` from the browser is that the former has `/people/users/123456/classPath/lib`, like your `use lib` pragma specifies, while the latter has `/people/users/m089269/classPath/lib`. That's kind of bizarre. (If anything, I'd have expected the reverse, in the case of symlinks.)

Comment: That's beacuse I was changing things to hide company info.

Comment: @Catfish: Maybe you should check the file-permissions for `/people`, `/people/users`, `/people/users/123456/`, and so on, up through `/people/users/123456/classPath/lib/Path/Class.pm`, and make sure that all of them are world-readable and world-executable. It's possible that, when you run the script from the browser, it's running as a different user, one that doesn't share all of your file-permissions.

Comment: I just remembered it's because the location of my test.pl file can't see the /people mount. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Catfish: Uh, you're welcome, though I'm not sure how helpful I actually ended up being. :-P

Answer (score 2):

When the script is run in the command line, `@INC` contains a path where Path/Class.pm might be found. This is apparently not true in the web browser case.

Make sure you get a good understanding of the script's working directory and `@INC` values when run as a web server, and figure out how to get the appropriate path (the parent of Path) into `@INC` if needed.

Start by dumping `@INC` in both cases and comparing them, to see what path might not be there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a debian user :

```
$ sudo apt-get install libpath-class-perl
```